# How to accumulate results from pool.apply_async call?

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, pool

I want to make calls to pool.apply_async(func) and accumulate the results as soon as they are available without waiting for each other.

```py
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

chrNames=['chr1','chr2','chr3']
sims=[1,2,3]



def accumulate_chrBased_simBased_result(chrBased_simBased_result,accumulatedSignalArray,accumulatedCountArray):
    signalArray = chrBased_simBased_result[0]
    countArray = chrBased_simBased_result[1]

    accumulatedSignalArray += signalArray
    accumulatedCountArray += countArray


def func(chrName,simNum):
    print('%s %d' %(chrName,simNum))

    result=[]
    signal_array=np.full((10000,), simNum, dtype=float)
    count_array = np.full((10000,), simNum, dtype=int)
    result.append(signal_array)
    result.append(count_array)

    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':

    accumulatedSignalArray = np.zeros((10000,), dtype=float)
    accumulatedCountArray = np.zeros((10000,), dtype=int)

    numofProcesses = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(numofProcesses)

    for chrName in chrNames:
        for simNum in sims:
            result= pool.apply_async(func, (chrName,simNum,))
            accumulate_chrBased_simBased_result(result.get(),accumulatedSignalArray,accumulatedCountArray)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print(accumulatedSignalArray)
    print(accumulatedCountArray)
```

In this way, each pool.apply_async call waits for other call to end. 
Is there a way do get rid of this waiting for each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `result.get()` on each iteration, and making the main process wait for the function to be ready in doing so.

Please find below a working version, with prints showing that accumulation is done when "func" is ready, and adding random sleeps to ensure sizable execution time differences.

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
from time import time, sleep
from random import random

chrNames=['chr1','chr2','chr3']
sims=[1,2,3]



def accumulate_chrBased_simBased_result(chrBased_simBased_result,accumulatedSignalArray,accumulatedCountArray):    
    signalArray = chrBased_simBased_result[0]
    countArray = chrBased_simBased_result[1]

    accumulatedSignalArray += signalArray
    accumulatedCountArray += countArray


def func(chrName,simNum):

    result=[]
    sleep(random()*5)
    signal_array=np.full((10000,), simNum, dtype=float)
    count_array = np.full((10000,), simNum, dtype=int)
    result.append(signal_array)
    result.append(count_array)
    print('%s %d' %(chrName,simNum))

    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':

    accumulatedSignalArray = np.zeros((10000,), dtype=float)
    accumulatedCountArray = np.zeros((10000,), dtype=int)

    numofProcesses = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(numofProcesses)

    results = []
    for chrName in chrNames:
        for simNum in sims:
            results.append(pool.apply_async(func, (chrName,simNum,)))

    for i in results:
        print(i)

    while results:
        for r in results[:]:
            if r.ready():
                print('{} is ready'.format(r))
                accumulate_chrBased_simBased_result(r.get(),accumulatedSignalArray,accumulatedCountArray)
                results.remove(r)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print(accumulatedSignalArray)
    print(accumulatedCountArray)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My only concern is the memory usage of results when we have lots of chrNames and sims, then results will take lot's of space right?

Comment: Is there a way to accumulate the result of a pool.apply_async   call whenever possible without collecting them in a list like structure? Since this may reduce memory footprint.

Comment: I don't think you will run into issues with this, because apply_async actually returns: `class multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult`. 
You need to call get() on AsyncResult to actually get the value.